# How do you activate a trigger on all records?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have an UPDATE/INSERT trigger on a table that uses a lookup to set a value. The lookups have now changed and I wanted to run the trigger on every record.

Is there an easy way to activate the trigger on every record in the table? I have tried a simple update, such as

```
update INDIVIDUAL_LOC
set EDIT_LINK=1
```

however this doesnt activate the trigger.

The trigger code is:

```
DECLARE
    @sCountry   Varchar(254),
    @sLeftPostcode  Varchar(10),
    @sPartPostcode  Varchar(10),
    @nIndRef    Integer,
    @sAttrCode  Varchar(254),
    @nAttrCodeRef   Integer

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM app_profile WHERE section = 'TRIGGERS' AND entry = 'RGS Region Attribute Trigger 2' AND value = 'Y' )
    BEGIN
    --add check for validity of address
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE inserted.main_location = 'Y' AND inserted.valid_from <= getdate() AND (inserted.valid_to > getdate() OR inserted.valid_to IS NULL))
        BEGIN
        SELECT @sCountry = location.country, @sLeftPostcode = LEFT(location.postcode,2), @sPartPostcode = SUBSTRING(location.postcode, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', location.postcode)), @nIndRef = inserted.individual_ref
        FROM inserted, location
        WHERE inserted.location_ref = location.location_ref

        IF @sCountry = 'Singapore'
            SET @sAttrCode = 'SING'
        ELSE IF @sCountry = 'Hong Kong'
            SET @sAttrCode = 'HK'
        ELSE IF @sCountry = 'Republic of Ireland'
            SET @sAttrCode = 'IRL'
        ELSE IF @sCountry = 'UK'
            BEGIN
            SELECT @sAttrCode = lookup_short_desc
            FROM lookup, lookup_type
            WHERE lookup_type.lookup_type_ref = lookup.lookup_type_ref
            AND lookup_type.lookup_type_code = 'PCODE2'
            AND lookup.lookup_code = @sLeftPostcode
            AND lookup.valid_from <= getdate() AND (lookup.valid_to >= getdate() OR lookup.valid_to IS NULL)

            IF @sAttrCode IS NULL
                SELECT @sAttrCode = lookup_short_desc
                FROM lookup, lookup_type
                WHERE lookup_type.lookup_type_ref = lookup.lookup_type_ref
                AND lookup_type.lookup_type_code = 'PCODE2'
                AND lookup.lookup_code = @sPartPostcode
                AND lookup.valid_from <= getdate() AND (lookup.valid_to >= getdate() OR lookup.valid_to IS NULL)
            END

        IF @sAttrCode IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @nAttrCodeRef = lookup_ref
            FROM lookup
            WHERE lookup_type_ref = 339
            AND lookup_code = @sAttrCode
            AND lookup.valid_from <= getdate() AND (lookup.valid_to >= getdate() OR lookup.valid_to IS NULL)
        ELSE
            SELECT @nAttrCodeRef = lookup_ref
            FROM lookup
            WHERE lookup_type_ref = 339
            AND lookup_code = 'NOREG'
            AND lookup.valid_from <= getdate() AND (lookup.valid_to >= getdate() OR lookup.valid_to IS NULL)

        IF @nAttrCodeRef IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
            --Check whether this exact attribute already exists or not
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM attribute WHERE individual_ref = @nIndRef AND attr_code_ref = @nAttrCodeRef)
                BEGIN
                --Check whether the attribute already exists or not
                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM attribute WHERE individual_ref = @nIndRef AND code_type = 339)
                    UPDATE attribute SET attribute_code = @sAttrCode, attr_code_ref = @nAttrCodeRef, valid_to = null WHERE individual_ref = @nIndRef AND code_type = 339
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO attribute ( individual_ref, code_type, attribute_code, attr_code_ref, valid_from )
                    VALUES ( @nIndRef, 339, @sAttrCode, @nAttrCodeRef, getdate() )
                END
            END

        END
    END
END
```

Comment: What is the DDL for your Trigger? If it's just an `AFTER UPDATE` or `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger, then yes, it's triggering. *(I smell a trigger that assumes only 1 row is only ever updated/inserted.)*

Comment: Need some clues about the trigger

Comment: Most likely the logic in your trigger is not correct and assumes a single row is updated.

Comment: Why not just execute the relevant code of the trigger manually?

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw!!! It assumes there is only row being inserted or updated (not sure what this trigger fires on). SQL Server does not fire a trigger for every row, it fires it once per operation. If you have multiple rows in your insert/update this will not do what you want. Triggers need to be set based. You also should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Seems like my nose was right, As Sean said, SQL Server doesn't fire a trigger by row, it's fires a trigger per DML statement. If you run an `UPDATE` statement against 1 or 1,000,000,000 rows, the trigger will fire once. SQL  is a set based language; treat your data as sets, not an individuals (that's what it is at the end of the day).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - Im relatively new to triggers and have inherited this code. There will only ever be one record so this isnt a problem... except in this instance where I want it to fire on every record.

Comment: "except in this instance " is exactly why triggers like this are the spawn of the devil. What happens in the future when the code changes and this rule is no longer the case. I actually know a guy who had his business close the doors because they had triggers like this everywhere and the cost to fix it (required by law for auditing) was too much.

Comment: *"There will only ever be one record"* and yet you now have a scenario where this isn't the case. Triggers should **never** assume that one row will be affected. Even if every operation in your system/application would only affect 1 row treat it as a dataset, otherwise you end up in a scenario like this. You have 2 options here, effectively. Update your trigger to be set based (this is the answer), or `UPDATE` your rows 1 row at a time (not the answer).

Comment: I had forgotten in my newness that triggers were set based based... writing for a set is the answer. One for after Christmas. Thanks for the pointers - very helpful!

Comment: Let us know if you need some help rewriting this into something more useful. Nothing worse to somebody fairly new than inheriting something poorly written. Die by fire I guess. :)